# HTML <dialog> tag modal scrolling to bottom on open

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

When using the `dialog` HTML tag and calling the `.showModal()` method, it seems that when the modal content is longer than the dialog display area, the dialog will scroll automatically to the bottom on every open. Is there a clean way to suppress this behavior, so that the dialog content will stay at the very top on open?

```js
document.getElementById("openDialog").addEventListener("click", () => document.getElementById("modal").showModal());

document.getElementById("closeDialog").addEventListener("click", () => document.getElementById("modal").close());
```

```html
<button id="openDialog">Open</button>
<dialog id='modal'>
  <h1>Hello world 1</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 2</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 3</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 4</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 5</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 6</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 7</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 8</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 9</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 10</h1>
  <button id="closeDialog">Close</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: It's the button gaining the focus and causing scrolling. Disabling the button will prevent it to be focused (enable in a timeout when the dialog is opened, and re-disable on close), but that's rather a hack than a clean solution.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu , I am currently using `scrollIntoView()` on the topmost element and it's kind of hack-ish too. Knowing that it's the button causing the issue... I can probably work around it by using some other elements, thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can also add a borderless fake button with zero dimensions and transparent background at the beginning of the dialog.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, I just replaced my button with a `<a>` tag without a `href` and all is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the explanation by @Teemu in the question's comments, the reason for this behavior is due to the `button` element getting focused on load.

For my case, I am using the button as a dismiss button, thus replacing the `button` with an `a` tag without the `href` attribute would solve the problem.

```js
document.getElementById("openDialog").addEventListener("click", () => document.getElementById("modal").showModal());

document.getElementById("closeDialog").addEventListener("click", () => document.getElementById("modal").close());
```

```html
<button id="openDialog">Open</button>
<dialog id='modal'>
  <h1>Hello world 1</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 2</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 3</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 4</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 5</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 6</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 7</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 8</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 9</h1>
  <h1>Hello world 10</h1>
  <a id="closeDialog">Close</button>
</dialog>
```